# Why are instances of my mocked class sharing attributes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking

I've got the following 3 files:

*shape.py*

```
import danger_import

class Polygon:
  def __init__(self, height=10, width=10):
    self.height = height
    self.width = width
    self.isActive = False

  def activate():
    self.isActive = True
```

*polygon_utility.py*

```
import shape

poly1 = None
poly2 = None

def activate_polygon():
  poly1.activate()
  if False:
    poly2.activate()

if __name__ != '__main__':
  poly1 = shape.Polygon()
  poly2 = shape.Polygon(4,12)
```

*test_polygon_utility.py*

```
import pytest
import sys
from unittest import mock

sys.modules['danger_import'] = mock.MagicMock()
import polygon_utility
import shape

@mock.patch('shape.Polygon')
def test_activate_polygon(mock_poly):
  polygon_utility.poly1 = mock_poly()
  polygon_utility.poly2 = mock_poly(4,12)
  polygon_utility.activate_polygon()
  assert polygon_utility.poly1.activate.call_count == 1
  assert polygon_utility.poly2.activate.call_count == 0
```

Basically I have this polygon class that I will be creating several polygons from. The polygon utility manages several polygons based on some logic I did not include. I am intending to unit test the activate_polygon function, which relies on the polygons object existing.for that I am importing the shape file so that I can create mock instances of the Polygon class. then i assign them to the global variables poly1 and poly2 in the file I am unit testing, and attempt to run the function.

When I run this unit test I get a failure on the second assertion. it seems that for some reason the 2 polygon instances I have created are tied together. Could anyone explain to me why that is and how I would go about getting the behavior I want?

Answer (score 0):

Your `@mock.patch` decorator is mocking the constructor for Polygon. You're then assigning `poly1` and `poly2` to a call of that constructor. The constructor's return value will be the same though; they will both be `mock_poly.return_value`, which is why the activate call count is > 0 for `poly2`.

There are a couple ways to accomplish this, but the use of globals here is worrying. By mocking the globals, you'd be modifying their value for the entire runtime of the test(s), so your results may vary and be unexpected. So, I would encourage you to look at refactoring how `polygon_utility.py` is done. In the short term, here's how I think you can fix your mocking/assertion issue:

```
@mock.patch('shape.Polygon')
def test_activate_polygon(mock_poly):
    polygon_utility.poly1 = mock.Mock()
    polygon_utility.poly2 = mock.Mock()
    polygon_utility.activate_polygon()
    assert polygon_utility.poly1.activate.call_count == 1
    assert polygon_utility.poly2.activate.call_count == 0
```